# zoneminder not creating local unix sockets for streaming

Tags: php, sockets, ubuntu

My configuration is:

- Ubuntu Precise 12.04
- Zoneminder (from ubuntu official repositories) 1.25.0
- Apache 2.2.22
- Php 5.3.10

Basically my syslog (and web_php.log created by the apache zoneminder cgi-bin) shows

```
03/12/13 17:42:20.307107 web_php[5514].ERR [socket_sendto( /var/run/zm/zms-347773s.sock ) failed: No such file or directory] at /usr/share/zoneminder/includes/functions.php line 2322
```

When I look at /var/run/zm

```
srwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data    0 Mar 12 17:42 zmdc.sock
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    5 Mar 12 17:42 zm.pid
srwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data    0 Mar 13 18:01 zms-347773w.sock
```

Note the w vs the s in the socket file name. Any ideas as to why the s file is not getting created.